# Can I omit "and" that links two clauses when speaking?

Tags: conjunction-reduction

In speaking, can I just use a comma between the two that-clauses, or do I have to add the word "and" and say "and that make me feel I have no excuse not to work hard."

> One thing I do in the morning is watch motivational videos that make
> me feel a sense of urgency, that make me feel I have no excuse not to
> work hard.

Comment: The conjunction is optional. Try saying the statements to somebody to see which you think is more effective, and go with that.

Comment: @RonaldSole, thank you for your comments. Is the conjunction optional in writing?

Comment: It depends on the context. It's equally correct to say: **I came across John, I also spotted Jane**.  And **I came across John and I also spotted Jane. In real life, you are more likely to omit the conjunction if the second part of the sentence is an afterthought. Instead of a comma, you could use a semi-colon to separate the two halves of the sentence. But the  use of the conjunction might be more appropriate in some contexts than in others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample sentence works either with the comma or with the "and." The comma, however, gives it a slightly different feel: when you use the comma, the point that comes after the comma suggests an elaboration, a further description, or maybe just a rephrasing of the point that comes before the comma. Contrast the following:

> When I get up in the morning, I like to watch videos that teach me
> something, that make me laugh.

This would be kind of a strange formulation. It appears that the speaker is just listing a couple of types of videos that he likes to watch in the morning. You wouldn't normally use a comma in a two-element list (although it's not unheard of), so "and" or "or" would work better here (with "and" more likely suggesting that the speaker likes videos that are both funny and education, and "or" more likely suggesting that he likes videos that into either single category). A comma would make sense if funny videos were in some sense an elaboration of educational videos, but it's not evident, at least from the provided context, how that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

No, your sentence is not correct. If you have a list of two different things, you need to join them with a conjunction.

The only way this structure could work without a conjunction is if the two "that" clauses *mean the same thing*. The two clauses in your example don't mean the same thing, so the grammar is bad.

Here's a different version of that sentence where the two "that" clauses are different ways of saying the same thing:

> One thing I do in the morning is watch motivational videos that make me feel a sense of urgency, that make me feel *I have to get this done right now or there'll be big trouble*.

Since the two "that" clauses are the same thing --not a list of two different things-- no conjunction is required.